# Compiling and installing programs as non-root in home-dir?

Tags: linux, unix, solaris

I'm trying to compile programs under Solaris in my Home directory.
Ive had experience with simple installs which work with just

```
   $> CD src
   $> ./configure --prefix=/home/peter
   $> make
   $> make install
```

But with more involved programs, with dependencies on special libraries, how do I have the system look into my home directory for these? and how would I compile them into my home dir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have to do things like that when I cross compile applications. If ./configure supports it, you can check with --help, you can do something like the following

```
./configure --extra-ldflags=-L/root/Installs/ffmpeg/forWin/usr/lib --extra-cflags=-I/root/Installs/ffmpeg/forWin/usr/include
```

There's one entry for libraries, and one for includes, however, there is always the old school way of just appending it before either configure or make

```
LDFLAGS='-L/root/Installs/ffmpeg/forWin/usr/lib' CFLAGS='-I/root/Installs/ffmpeg/forWin/usr/include' ./configure
LDFLAGS='-L/root/Installs/ffmpeg/forWin/usr/lib' CFLAGS='-I/root/Installs/ffmpeg/forWin/usr/include' make
```

For make I think they can be specified either before or after, however don't quote me on it.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you're building software that uses `configure`, most `configure` scripts will allow you to specify paths to third party libs. Do `configure --help` and look for --with-feature=/path/to/software.

As other answers have mentioned, `configure` and other scripts tend to look at the environment variables `CFLAGS` `LDFLAGS` and `LIBS`. You can set CFLAGS with -I/include/paths and -L/library/paths and that may help.

Worst case, you may need to edit Makefiles to reset those paths.

If you want the software to live someplace, `configure` scripts tend to have --prefix= argument to specify install dir. Or you may have to edit a Makefile.